# C++: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour [-Waddress]

Tags: c++

I've started learning/using bits of C++, Ruby background.

Can someone help me with the below code?

I have no idea what's wrong but it's causing this error message:

> C++: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified
>   behaviour [-Waddress]

```
void OnUserConnect(LocalUser* user)
{
    if (user->MyClass->name.c_str() == "user") {
        ServerInstance->SNO->WriteToSnoMask('a', "Triggered: %s", user->MyClass->name.c_str());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparison `user->MyClass->name.c_str() == "user"` compares two *pointers*, and two pointers that will never be the same.

Since you seem to be using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) you can use the equality [comparison operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) directly without needing to get a pointer:

```
if (user->MyClass->name == "user") { ... }
```

***If*** for some strange reason you want to compare using C-style string pointers, you must use [`std::strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp).

Comment: Thanks, this solved the question. Why do I need to use `.c_str()` in the notice then?

Comment: @user6213803 You mean the `WriteToSnoMask` call? that function probably expects a C-style string and not a C++ `std::string` object.

Comment: @user6213803. The signature `WriteToSnoMask (char letter, const char *text,...)` uses a formatting string (similar to `printf`), the the "string" formatter `%s` requires a C-style string `char*` and doesn't work with a `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks both, understand now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare a `char*` variable and a `const char*` literal. if you want to use this comparison you must use `strcmp` function. You can replace the below condition to yours

```
if(!strcmp(user->MyClass->name.c_str(),"user")
```